# Debian 9.2.1 "Stretch" updating at all?

Tags: bash, debian, upgrade

I'm brand new to Debian, was using Ubuntu. So please forgive my assumed ignorance here!

I'm quite security minded, and my morning routine starts with "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" it's been a week now and nothing has been updated yet. My etc/apt/sources.list looks functional. With Ubuntu there were updates almost daily. Is this normal behaviour? Don't want to be un-patched! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly normal that Debian stable (currently 9.2, not sure why you write 9.2.1) gets no updates for weeks. Point releases are usually months apart:

- 9.0: 2017-06-17
- 9.1: 2017-07-22
- 9.2: 2017-10-08

Beyond that you get irregular security updates for individual packages, thus the frequency or security updates depends on which packages you've got installed. You can check https://www.debian.org/security/ for the latest security updates to make sure you didn't miss anything (only possible with a broken APT or network config).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Ubuntu is loosely based on a combination of Debian "testing" and "unstable".  At the time of this comment, Debian "Stretch" is Debian "stable."  What that means is that the software in the repo is mostly going to be OK working together in a cohesive and 'unbroken' way.  It also means that very few updates will be required, except for security updates.

In general, I use Debian "testing" for home use and Debian "stable" for servers.  If you are used to Ubuntu, Debian "stable" is probably not for you, since much of the software will be several point releases lower than the latest available.

However, if you are really committed to Debian "stable" as your general purpose OS, I would recommend making sure that you have "backports" listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

And for further reading on Debian releases and backports in general:

[Debian Releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/)

[Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)

Comment: It's faster to use geomirror: `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main`

Comment: backports is not necessarily a good idea. They can break functionality in unexpected ways. You ought to be more experienced to be using them too

Answer (score 1):

There are [unattended upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) in Debian. You should get some view on them with this command:

```
grep -B1 -A3 unattended-upgrade /var/log/apt/history.log
```